# Search and Remove Functions in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have a program used to manage a database of records called "client_DB". The array "client_DB" is composed of customer cell phone call records.  Each customer call record contains eight fields, which are as follows: 1) a ten digit cell phone number (string, no dashes), 2) the number of relay stations used in making the call (integer), 3) the length of the call in minutes (integer), 4) the net cost of the call (double), 5) the tax rate (double), 6) the call tax (double), 7) the total cost of the call (double) and 8) string field called "discount_aval with a value of "yes" or "no".  The array  client_DB has a capacity (SIZE) of 20 records.

It reads from an input file first called "client_data.txt" which is composed of these values:

```
9546321555  0   0   yes
5612971340  5   50  no
3051234567  8   25  no
7542346622  24  17  no
3054432762  15  30  yes
9544321011  50  100 yes
8776219988  87  82  yes
9042224556  4   5   yes
7877176590  11  1   no
5617278899  20  45  no
9546321555  4   3   yes
5612971340  79  86  no
3051234567  8   25  no
7542346622  24  118 no
3054432762  115 25  yes
9544321011  43  10  yes
8776219988  265 22  yes
9042224556  2   5   yes
7877176590  89  67  no
5617278899  40  56  no
```

My Remove function only removes the first value, if i type in to remove any other value, it simply wont! My Search function simply gives me back 2 numbers. Which is off and its not what i want. Help? I want to be able to ask the user for a cellnumber, then have it search the entire array and find it and delete it. I want my search grab an input also, find it and give me back its location. I tried but i dont know what i did wrong. In my main, i called both functions when the user selects it from the function Menu.
heres my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

//************************************************************************
//Name:  Kevin          Due Date: 022113
//Instructor: Dr. Bullard               Total Points:  100 pts
//Assignment2: client_call.cpp          UsIDFAU: 
//:


using namespace std;

const int CAPACITY = 20;

 class client_db
  {
  public:
    string cellnum;
    int numofrelay;
    int call_length;
    double net_cost;
    double tax_rate;
    double call_tax;
    double total_cost;
    string discount_aval;
   };

bool IsFull(int); //returns true if the array is full; otherwise false.
bool IsEmpty(int count);// returns ture if the array is empty; otherwise false.

void Add(client_db A[], int & count, client_db & db);
void Remove(client_db A[], int *count, string name);// removes an item from the array if it is there
void Print_DB(client_db A[], int count);//prints to output file
void Call_stats(client_db A[], int count);// prints all the items in the array
int Search_DB(client_db A[], int count, string name); //if the name is in the array, its location is returned
//                                        //otherwise return -1;
//
bool IsFull(int count)
////Description: Determines if the array is full
{
    return (count == CAPACITY);
}

bool IsEmpty(int count)
////Description: Determines if the array is empty
{
    return (count == 0);
}

void Process (client_db A[], int count)
{

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
    if (A[i].numofrelay >=1 && A[i].numofrelay<=5)
    {
        A[i].tax_rate=0.01;
        A[i].net_cost = ((A[i].numofrelay / 50.0)*0.40*A[i].call_length);

    }
    else if (A[i].numofrelay >=6 && A[i].numofrelay<=11)
    {
        A[i].tax_rate=0.03;
        A[i].net_cost = ((A[i].numofrelay / 50.0)*0.40*A[i].call_length);


    }
    else if (A[i].numofrelay>=12 && A[i].numofrelay<=20)
    { 
        A[i].tax_rate=0.05;
        A[i].net_cost = ((A[i].numofrelay / 50.0)*0.40*A[i].numofrelay);


    }
    else if (A[i].numofrelay >=21 && A[i].numofrelay<=50)
    {
       A[i].tax_rate =0.08;
       A[i].net_cost = ((A[i].numofrelay / 50.0)*0.40*A[i].call_length);


    }
    else if (A[i].numofrelay >50)
    {
        A[i].tax_rate =0.12;
        A[i].net_cost = ((A[i].numofrelay / 50.0)*0.40*A[i].call_length);


    }
    A[i].call_tax = ((A[i].tax_rate)/(100))*(A[i].net_cost);
    A[i].total_cost = A[i].net_cost + A[i].call_tax;
    }
}

void Print_DB(client_db A[], int count)

//Description: Prints the items stored in A to the standard i/o device
{

    string filename;
    cout<<"Enter output filename: "; //geting filename
    cin>>filename;

    ofstream output; //declaring an output file stream

    output.open(filename.c_str()); // c_str() converts a C++ string into a 
                                  // c-style string (char array) &
                                  //open binds an ofstream to a file
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {

        output<<A[i].cellnum<<"\t"
              <<A[i].numofrelay<<"\t"
              <<A[i].call_length<<"\t"
              <<A[i].net_cost<<"\t"
              <<A[i].tax_rate<<"\t"
              <<A[i].call_tax<<"\t"
              <<A[i].total_cost<<"\t"
              <<A[i].discount_aval<<endl;

    }

    output.close();
}

int Search(client_db A[], int count, string cellnum)
////Description: Locates cellnumbers in A's fields
{
    cout<<"Please enter a phone number:   "<<endl;
    cin>>cellnum;

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if (cellnum == A[i].cellnum)
        {
            cout<<i<<endl;
        }

    }
   return -1;
}

void Add(client_db A[], int &count)
////Description: Adds key to the array
{
    if (!IsFull(count))
    {
        cout<<"Enter a cellphone number, number of relay stations and the call lenght and if a discount is available: ";
        cin>>A[count].cellnum>>A[count].numofrelay>>A[count].call_length>>A[count].discount_aval;
        count++;

    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"The list is full\n";
    }

}

void Add(client_db A[], int &count, client_db &db)
////Description: Adds key to the array
{
    if (!IsFull(count))
    {
        A[count] = db; 
        count++;

    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"The list is FULL! \n";
    }

}
void Remove(client_db A[], int *count, string cellnum )

////Description: Removes the number from the array is it is there
{

    int loc = Search(A,*count,cellnum);

    if (IsEmpty(*count))
    {
        cout<<"There is nothing to remove\n";
        return;
    }
    else if (loc == -1)
    {
        cout<<"Number is not in data\n";
    }
    else
    {
        for(int j=loc; j<(*count)-1; j++)
        {
            A[j] = A[j+1];
        }
        (*count)--;

    }
}


void Call_stats(client_db A[],int count) // prints to screen
{

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        cout<<A[i].cellnum<<"\t"
            <<A[i].numofrelay<<"\t"
            <<A[i].call_length<<"\t"
            <<A[i].discount_aval<<endl;

    }
}
void Menu ()
{
    cout<<"The values of the filename you entered have been recognized"<<endl;
    cout<<"Please enter the letter of your application of choice"<<endl;
    cout<<"       "<<endl;
    cout<<"************  WELCOME TO THE MAIN MENU  ************"<<endl;
    cout<<" Add an item...........................A"<<endl;
    cout<<" Remove an item........................R"<<endl;
    cout<<" Search for an item....................S"<<endl;
    cout<<" Print current data....................P"<<endl;
    cout<<" Print to output file..................O"<<endl;
    cout<<"****************************************************"<<endl;
}



int main()
{

    char answer;
    char answer2;
    client_db CLIENT[CAPACITY]; //declaring database
    int count = 0;   //initializing count
    string cellnum;

    string filename;
    cout<<"Hello!, this program holds clients call data records."<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter input filename: "; //geting filename
    cin>>filename;

    ifstream input; //declaring an input file stream

    input.open(filename.c_str()); // c_str() converts a C++ string into
        while(count<CAPACITY && !input.eof()) //reading until the end of the file (eof=end-of-file)
    {


        input>>CLIENT[count].cellnum
        >>CLIENT[count].numofrelay
        >>CLIENT[count].call_length
        >>CLIENT[count].discount_aval;

        count++;

    }

    do
{

  Menu();
  cout<<"Please enter a command letter:  "<<endl;
    cin>>answer;
    client_db db;

    switch (answer)
{

case 'A' : 
    cout<<"Enter a cellphone number, number of relay stations and the call lenght and if a discount is available: "<<endl;
    cin>>db.cellnum>>db.numofrelay>>db.call_length>>db.discount_aval;
    Add(CLIENT, count, db);
break;
case 'R' : Remove(CLIENT,&count,cellnum);
break;
case 'S' : 
    Search(CLIENT,count,cellnum);

break;
case 'P' : Call_stats(CLIENT,count);
break;
case 'O' :
    Process(CLIENT,count); //how do i set the precision for this?
    Print_DB(CLIENT,count);
break;
    }
     cout<<"Would you like to make another command?(y/n):   "<<endl;
   cin>>answer2;
} while (answer2 == 'Y' || answer2 == 'y');
 cout<<"Goodbye"<<endl;
    return 0;






}
```

Comment: The Function Search gives me back 2 numbers. Why? for example, if i search for 3051234567 which is in array[2].. it gives me back a 2, then a 12. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be exactly what you want the function to return. Note that the phone number at index 2 and 12 are the same. If fact, it seems that are only 10 unique phone numbers in the list. Therefore, you will get 2 numbers as output when searching for each of those 10 numbers, since they all have one duplicate.

If you only want the first match to be printed, simply add a `break;` as follows:

```
for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    if (!(A[i].cellnum.compare(cellnum)))
    {
        cout<<i<<endl;
        break;
    }

}
```

in the Search function. If identical phone number are not desired, you could consider checking this before allowing the user to search for a phone number.

EDIT: 
I see that your Remove function is not working properly either. You try to get the index of the phone number by using the Search function, but the search function always returns -1.
I would add the `break` as I mentioned above, and then return `i` instead of -1. Declare `i` outside of the for loop for this to work.

As you want all occurrences to be deleted upon choosing Remove, I would do the following:

In your main function:

```
case 'R' : 
cout<<"Please enter a phone number:   "<<endl;
cin>>cellnum;
Remove(CLIENT,&count,cellnum); break;
```

and

```
case 'S' : 
cout<<"Please enter a phone number:   "<<endl;
cin>>cellnum;
Search(CLIENT,count,cellnum); break;
```

Search:

```
int Search(client_db A[], int count, string cellnum){
   int index = -1;

   for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
   {
       if (!(A[i].cellnum.compare(cellnum)))
       {
           cout<<i<<endl;
           index = i;
           break;
       }
   }
   return index;
}
```

And Remove:

```
void Remove(client_db A[], int *count, string cellnum ){
int loc;
while((loc=Search(A,*count,cellnum)) != -1){
      if (IsEmpty(*count)){
          cout<<"There is nothing to remove\n";
          return;
      }
      else if (loc == -1){
          cout<<"Number is not in data\n";
      }
      else{
          for(int j=loc; j<(*count)-1; j++)
          {
              A[j] = A[j+1];
          }
          (*count)--;

      }
}
}
```

Comment: You are totally right, I want both of those to be deleted. In My remove function, It only deletes the first cell phonenumber. i want it to find the locations, which are found in Search, then both to be deleted

Comment: Adding the `break` would result in only the first occurrence of the phone number being deleted. I would add an else statement and return -1 if no number was found, and return the index otherwise. Then call the remove function in a while loop until the given index is -1.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it! btw since you are the only one helping me, I have a function called Process that makes calculations. These calculations are printed to an output file along with everything in the array. Where do i stuff the code for setting the precision on what gets printed to the file (not the screen)?

Comment: You can use `std::setprecision` for that (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/).
like: `myfile << std::setprecision(5) << value` would print `value` to file with 5 decimals.

Comment: I need to use this. cout.setf(ios::fixed);
                    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
             cout.precision(2);          but where do i put it?

Comment: For example, if you tried the function Print_DB, it would print the values to an output file but not in set precision. The function process makes these calculations, however i dont know where to put that code. I tried everywhere and it still prints to the file with unwanted decimal place values

Comment: Why do you need to use that? I can't tell you for sure if that works for writing to file too, but I would put it in your main function, or if it's different for each time you write, put it right before...

Comment: add this line: `output<<setiosflags(ios::fixed)<<std::setprecision(2)<<setiosflags(ios::showpoint);` in your Print_DB function, right after opening the file.

Comment: It wont let me add that. It says setiosflags and setprecision are undefined. Do i need to add a library?